# Did Kayin and Hevel grow quickly or were they born fully developed?

Tags: midrash, age, parashat-bereishit

The sefer `Seder Hadorot` brings different opinions as to how old Hevel was when he was killed by Kayin.

`Bershit Rabbah Ch. 22:` 50 days (or 90 days [Seder Hadorot says 50 is a printing mistake])

`Ibn Ezra:` 1 year

`Tanchuma, Abarbanel and Josephus:` 100 years.

According to the former opinions... does this mean that Kayin and Hevel developed really quickly or were they somehow born fully developed?

Answer (score 1):

One of my Rebbes said in the name of the Zohar that they were born developed like a 20 year old.

Comment: Now we understand בעצב תלדי בנים. They must have been huge!

Comment: And she tried to nurse one, but he bit her, so she named him קייַען.

Comment: Anyone know where the source of this is? Thanks. Best I've found so far is Bereishis Rabbah 14:7 saying that Adam and Chava were created as 20 year olds.